# template literal inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 4 user profiles pictures saved in my *assets/img* folder. I'm attempting to attach the appropriate profile picture to its user based on the user's name using jQuery. For example, if the user name is adam, I wanna select adam.png in the img folder.

```
var $profilephoto = $('<img class="profile-photo" src="assets/img/${home.user}.png">');
```

However, the images displaying on the page are broken which leads me to think the link somewhat is incorrect? I tried to put double quotes around `${home.user}` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Use backticks to create a template literal, not single quotes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```js
var $profilephoto = $(`<img class="profile-photo" src="assets/img/${home.user}.png">`);
```